# How to return String from onResponse? Retrofit android studio

Tags: android, mysql, get, retrofit, retrofit2

I've seen a few similar questions but they don't seem to answer my problem exactly. I've got a method that is supposed to return a string. I am using retrofit, but in onresponse, I can't return a string? Below is the code.

```
public String getInformation(String information, String username) {

       

        String result;
        Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getInformation(information,username);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                 result = response.body().getMsg();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });
        
        return result;



    }
```

Comment: "I've got a method that is supposed to return a string" -- if that method will be called on a background thread, try `call.execute()` instead of `call.enqueue()`. If that method will be called on the main application thread, then it should not be set up to return a string, as it is a bad idea to do network I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks, I tried call.execute() and it threw an error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: That is because your method is being called on the main application thread. You need to adjust this method to not return a string. Instead, have it take some sort of callback that you can call from `onResponse()`. That way, `enqueue()` will handle the background threading for you, so your network I/O does not freeze the UI. See [y.allam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505373/115145).

Answer (score 2):

The `.enqueue` method will take time to get the response, so your method will return before `onResponse` callback gets called.

Try using a callback approach for `getInformation` method and make it `void`:

```
public void getInformation(String information, String username, MyCallback callback) {

        Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getInformation(information,username);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                 result = response.body().getMsg();
                 callback.success(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                 callback.failure(t)
            }

        });
}
```

With the `MyCallback` interface:

```
interface MyCallback {
    void success(String result);
    void failure(Throwable t);
}
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```
getInformation("Information", "Username", new MyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(String result) {
                // Use result
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(Throwable t) {
                // Display error
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I get the value of result from outside the getInformation call?

Comment: @AnonymousCardinal it's the last part in the answer, inside the `success` callback

Comment: Yes, but how would I get access to that variable from outside the method?

Comment: You can directly access it where you're calling the method, the place where you're calling it and passing the callback is "outside the method"!

Comment: I'm a little confused here, I'm a beginner. after getInformation has been called, how do I get the value of String result. I don't want to do anything in success other than pass the value of result outside of getInformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Result as output String wherever you want, as I used it in my adapter class in onBindViewHolder method, simply making object of the class from which string was sent and then calling the method (in which Interface was kept as parameter) & override success and failure method in adapter class and do whatever u want to do with this string......... Thanks a lot @y.allam & @Anonymous Cardinal :):)